# Cleaning up after calls to SMO Server and Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, smo

How do you make SMO release it's connections?

I have this code:

```
public static class SqlServerConnectionFactory
{
    public static Server GetSmoServer()
    {
        using (var c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var s = new ServerConnection(c);
            c.Close();
            return new Server(s);
        }
    }

    public static Database GetSmoDatabase(Server server)
    {
        var db = server.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"]];
        db.AutoClose = true;
        return db;
    }
}
```

Called like this from an ASP.Net MVC app run in IIS...:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        server = SqlServerConnectionFactory.GetSmoServer();
        database = SqlServerConnectionFactory.GetSmoDatabase(server);
        var vm = new SettingsIndexViewmodel(database);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

For every call I make to this index method a connection is spun up - and is not released again.

So after 20 calls to the page, I have 20 of the connections awaiting command. This eventually ends up with an exception, when I cannot make new connections, because the connection pool is full.

[image: sp_who]

What do I need to avoid this happening? I cannot seem to find a method on the SMO Server object like Dispose, close or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MSDN article [`Disconnecting from an Instance of SQL Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162216(v=SQL.100).aspx) might offer some help. It states that:

> When the [Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.connectionmanager.connect(v=SQL.100).aspx) method is called, the
>   connection is not automatically
>   released. The [Disconnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.connectionmanager.disconnect(v=SQL.100).aspx) method must
>   be called explicitly to release the
>   connection to the connection pool.
>   Also, you can request a non-pooled
>   connection. You do this by setting the
>   [NonPooledConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.connectionsettings.nonpooledconnection(v=SQL.100).aspx) property of the
>   [ConnectionContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.connectioncontext(v=SQL.100).aspx) property that
>   references the [ServerConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection(v=SQL.100).aspx) object

Comment: This worked. I just called this after I was done with the server object: server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();

Answer (score 2):

After reading everything i managed to properly disconnect by setting

```
server.ConnectionContext.NonPooledConnection = true;
```

and then after i get my database i can call

```
server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
```

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out for hours. This saved my life!