# Restore SQL Database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, database-restore

I am trying to restore sql databse using C# code.Backup is working fine. But when the restore the db it gives me an error.
I am using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;` for this operation.
The error is
{"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: RESTORE cannot process database 'TempDb' because it is in use by this session. 
It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation."}

In several posts it says set the database to the master. I also tried that.But it gives me the same error.
Connection string:connectionString = @"server=(local);Initial Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True;";

My code is as follows:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string databaseName = "TempDb";
        Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(openFileDialog1.FileName, DeviceType.File);
        sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;

        DataConnection dataConnection = new DataConnection();
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(dataConnection.DataBaseConnection);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
        sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        String dataFileLocation = db.FileGroups[0].Files[0].FileName;
        String logFileLocation = db.LogFiles[0].FileName;
        db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
        RelocateFile rf = new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation);


        sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation));
        sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(databaseName + "_log", logFileLocation));
        sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        sqlRestore.Complete += new ServerMessageEventHandler(sqlRestore_Complete);
        sqlRestore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
        sqlRestore.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(sqlRestore_PercentComplete);
        sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
        db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
        db.SetOnline();
        sqlServer.Refresh();
```

Comment: Take a look at [Cleaning up after calls to SMO Server and Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566632/cleaning-up-after-calls-to-smo-server-and-database).

Comment: When we restore Database using SQl server management studio we can chose the back up set. Using this code its restore only the first option.Can I configure that.

Comment: Possibly... you should post that as a new question, after checking for existing similar ones.  You did a good job of showing your code here, and doing so on the new question should prove helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
this code For Restore Database,Please Type Code In C#:

SqlConnection ObjConnection=new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
ObjConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand ObjCommand = new SqlCommand();
                ObjCommand.Connection = ObjConnection;
                ObjCommand.CommandText = "Use Master   ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET                 OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE  " +
                "Restore Database YourDatabaseName From Disk='" + LblPath.Text + "'" +
                "   ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
                ObjCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Help:LblPath.Text is a Label Control Contain Path Backup Database You!
Mojtaba From IRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database is still in use by other logins. try taking it to single user mode before restorations, it really helps. Make sure that you use the same connection object to take the database to single user mode, then restoration and then to bring back it to multi user mode.

you could try this,

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE <database name> SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", connection);

cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

return connection; //to use the same connection for restore activity and setting it to multi user mode again


//up on completion of restore activity, take the database to multi user mode.
//ALTER DATABASE <database name> SET MULTI_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for restore database

```
var conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"];
string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        try
        {
            cs.Open();
            String sqlquery = "Use Master ALTER DATABASE databasename SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE RESTORE DATABASE databasename FROM DISK ='" + txtRestoreFileLoc.Text + "' ALTER DATABASE databasename SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cs);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("restore complete");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```