# How to do SQL Server database back up and recovery in MVC 4

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, database-security

I want to do a backup of my SQL Server database via my program in ASP.Net MVC 4. Please help me on where to start as I have not done it before.

Thanks in  advance

Answer (score 1):

you can use Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo for back up and restore database
 [Code Project example using .Net 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26390/SQL-Server-2005-Database-Backup-and-Restore-using) .Hope this will match your requirement

Also look the same type of question
[Restore SQL Database using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639903/restore-sql-database-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

backup is simple, you can execute sql command in entity framework:

```
BACKUP DATABASE YourDB TO DISK = 'C:\Backups\YourDB.bak'
```